# How TFS will track the .PBL files of Powerbuilder code, does it track each and every functions, events of datawindow code inside of .PBL files?

Tags: git, tfs, powerbuilder

It will be really helpful if someone explain how the TFS will track the powerbuilder code. As you know Powerbuilder contains .PBL library files, inside that only we are having datawindows, windows, user_objects and all. Here the functions, logic of code are at the datawindow,window level.

Let say, Someone pushed .PBL library file code to server and another person also working on the same .PBL locally and person B pulling code from server , it is ending up in conflict. How the conflict can be resolved incase of .PBL and binary files?  because these cannot be easily resolved as it is not the text file.

So, it would be helpful if I got a clear explanation.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's nothing special about any particular file type. If it's binary content, it will be treated as binary content. If it's text content, it will be treated as text content. Can you please clarify your question and explain what your concern is?

Comment: I have updated the question now with little explanation. basically I want to know how the other files will be tracked other than text files because In powerbuilder PBL contains datawindow, windows etc so if changes happened on window means, some changes will be happened on PBL also. In this case , if conflict occurs how the PBL conflict can be resolved ? . Hope I explained clearly

Comment: Every version control tool treats binaries the same way when there's a conflict: You choose which version to take and lose the changes you don't take. In TFVC, the most common way to avoid problems like that are exclusive locks on files, so only one person can edit it at a time.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you please explain what if incase of I am using Git as a version control. Like resolving conflicts for text files, Should It require to resolve conflicts at binary level as well. Or Shall I assume that if I resolve the conflict for data windows,, the umberlla of data window which is PBL can be resolved automatically ?

Comment: If TFS isn't working, I believe TopWiz Software sells a source control system designed for PowerBuilder: https://www.topwizprogramming.com/wizsource.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re asking the right questions, but the wrong place.

No, you probably don’t want to source control PBLs, but objects individually. PowerBuilder has tools built into the IDE to do this.

However, the answer is too big for a StackOverflow question. It’s covered pretty well in the manuals (User Guide) and there used to be articles out on the web on this. Mike Cobb & Bruce Armstrong used to be the community deities on the subject; if you Google them, you should find some supplementary content if the manuals aren’t doing it for you.

Also note that because of discontinuation of support MS has made for TFS regarding standard protocols MS-itself created, depending on the PB version, you may not get PB to work with TFS unless you have it configured as a Git repository.

Good luck.

Comment: As a small comment to the OPs question, all objects in a PBL are exported to text files.  These are what are 'tracked' in TFS.  In general the binary files are not kept under source control.